# Validating to ensure name inputted

Tags: php, regex

Searched the web to find a regex to validate visitor name input in two parts but did not have much luck.

A "two parts" visitor name means for example `Joe Soap`, `Tom O'Fool`, etc.

I want to accept A-Z, a-z letters the 'symbol and at least one blank space.

I need something like the following to do the job

```
if( !preg_match("^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/i^", $vname) )
```

but this will not pass; it keeps returning message to input valid name.

Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: Your regular expression accepts hyphens `-`, but your question doesn't mention them. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"/^[a-z']+ [a-z']+$/i"
```